# innerHTML is not refreshing the window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use innerHTML with arrays and it does not work, 
but if i use document.write my function works properly and I get the following:
product 1
price 1
product 2
price 2
product 3
price 3
product 4
price 4
product 5
price 5 
Any help will be appreciated.
Following is the code:

```js
var items = [
  ["product 1", "price 1"],
  ["product 2", "price 2"],
  ["product 3", "price 3"],
  ["product 4", "price 4"],
  ["product 5", "price 5"]
];


function testButton() {

  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = items[i][j] + "<br>";
      /*document.write(items[i][j] + "<br>");*/
    }

  }

}
```

```css
#buttons {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttons" onclick="testButton()">Next</button>
```

Comment: seems to work, you overwrite button with price 1, then price 2 etc ... you'll only ever see "price 5" though

Comment: @JaromandaX is right, since the browser works too fast to recognize, you couldn't even know what happen in the middle of its work. So technically, the value has been changed, but you could only see the last one when the browser stopped to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build up the html in the loop and append it to a variable. Then after the loop ends, set the HTML for the button element.

```js
var items = [
  ["product 1", "price 1"],
  ["product 2", "price 2"],
  ["product 3", "price 3"],
  ["product 4", "price 4"],
  ["product 5", "price 5"]
];

function testButton() {
  var html = '';
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      html += items[i][j] + "<br>";
      /*document.write(items[i][j] + "<br>");*/
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
#buttons {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttons" onclick="testButton()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written replaces the contents of the button on each iteration of the for loop.

```
document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = items[i][j] + "<br>";
```

I *think* you want to append the contents, which I'm pretty sure is what successive calls to `document.write` does.

```
document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML += items[i][j] + "<br>";
```

You may need to clear this before starting the for loop depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a + sign helped a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. If you consider this answer helpful, don't forget to upvote/accept it :)